# Google map to show name of location if found, otherwise just the address

Tags: google-maps, google-maps-api-3

Can I use embedded Google map in my website to show the name of location if found, and if not found then just the address?

I can get my code to show the address in all cases but the name is showing up only in some cases. I have a few examples in http://www.yankeedesi.com/testmap.htm. If you look at the first row, I can get the map working with address but not with name of the place. In the second row, however both the cases are working.

[image]

The code I used for the first one is:

```
<iframe width="300" height="250" frameborder="0" style="border:0"
 src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?key=<MyKey>&q=910+11th+St,Anacortes+WA+98221">    
</iframe>
```

and for the second one is

```
<iframe width="300" height="250" frameborder="0" style="border:0" 
src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed/v1/place?
key=AIzaSyCpmbSHS59rVuyJGtIStR4CcGo2g3dNXF8
&q=Little+Calcutta+Restaurants,910+11th+St,Anacortes+WA+98221">
</iframe>
```

Now in the second case because Google map is unable to find the address with the name Little+Calcutta+Restaurants, it is not searching the address as well.

What I want is:
If the search with name is successful then show it with name, else search with address and ignore the name. Is that possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

yeah use geocoder

`var geocoder;`

add this to your initialize before making a map

`geocoder = new google.maps.Geocoder();`

```
function search(){
 var address = document.getElementById('address').value;
```

`geocoder.geocode( { 'address': address}, function(results, status) {
    if (status == google.maps.GeocoderStatus.OK) {
     //search complete
    } else {
      //search again but subtring your address
    }`

Comment: Thanks for the tip to use Geocoder. My code is in Classic ASP, so I looked up the usage of Geocoder in Classic ASP and used the solution provided in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22670925/how-to-use-geocoding-api-v3-in-classic-asp. However, I noticed that in some cases where the address is already mapped to some other location name, that name is showing up instead of the one I am passing. So, I decided to stick to showing the addresses in all cases instead of the names.