# How can I create links Google Maps that either use the place name in the query (for known places) or just the address otherwise?

Tags: google-maps

I am creating links to Google Maps for a large number of locations using this URL pattern:

```
https://www.google.com/maps?q=[query]
```

In many cases, Google knows that the particular business exists at that location. In those cases, I want to include the place/business name in the query so the resulting map shows additional information about the business (e.g. name, phone numbers, site URL, office hours, etc.). For example:

https://maps.google.com/?q=Child+Guidance+Center,+Inc.+525+Cabrillo+Park+Dr+#300+Santa+Ana,+CA+92701

But, if the place isn't known, including the business name in the query prevents the map from adding a marker to the correct address. For example:

https://maps.google.com/?q=Awesome+Paint+527+Cabrillo+Park+Dr+Santa+Ana,+CA+92701

It can cause the map to be totally zoomed out, or focus on a competing business with a somewhat similar name in the same general area.

How can I make this work better? I would like the map pin to always go in the correct location for the address I specify. If the business name I provide is known to Google at that address, then I'd like the nice panel of extra information. If it is not known, I just want the pin.

Thank you.

---

This similar question is asking about creating embedded maps, which is a slightly different case [Google map to show name of location if found, otherwise just the address](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24944089/google-map-to-show-name-of-location-if-found-otherwise-just-the-address). I'd prefer to avoid extensive use of the APIs because I'm worried about exceeding the free limit, but more generally geocoding the address that worked above (Child+Guidance+Center,+Inc.+525+Cabrillo+Park+Dr+#300+Santa+Ana,+CA+92701) returns zero results like so:

```
http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=Child+Guidance+Center,+Inc.+525+Cabrillo+Park+Dr+#300+Santa+Ana,+CA+92701
```

Comment: You could use geocoding as an admin; then you save the data to a file (JSON format), or to a database, ... .  Then you can make an embedded map that uses this data.  I think this would greatly reduce the risk of over usage.  You can push any information (website, cathegory for filtering, logo, ...)

Comment: I'm still concerned that geocoding the address that worked for the map link didn't return any results, so I'm not sure that geocoding would actually give me the information I need to know how Google would handle a given map query.